# TypeScript definitions for restivus.d.ts

Tags: javascript, meteor, typescript

The TypeScript definition I am referring to can be seen [here](https://github.com/shybyte/marcolixa/blob/master/.typescript/restivus.d.ts). I am using a Meteor package called [restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/blob/devel/README.md). To use it you basically call the constructor like so:

```
var Api = new Restivus({
    useDefaultAuth: true,
    prettyJson: true
});
```

Using the current definition file causes one error: `Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature`. The current definition:

```
declare module Restivus {
  export function configure(o: {})
  export function addCollection<T>(collection: Mongo.Collection<T>);
  export function addRoute<T>(path: string, conf: {}, routes: {});
}
```

Doesn't have a constructor and all the definitions I've come across used a class in order to call either new or constructor. How can I implement Restivus, so I don't have to do `declare var` it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the class declaration as well. The module declaration will build upon the class declaration. See [Merging Modules with Classes, Functions, and Enums](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#declaration-merging-merging-modules-with-classes-functions-and-enums).

```
declare class Restivus {
    constructor (options?: any);
}
declare module Restivus {
    export function configure(o: {})
    export function addCollection<T>(collection: Mongo.Collection<T>);
    export function addRoute<T>(path: string, conf: {}, routes: {});
}
```

**Edit:**

New definition that works with their examples.

```
declare class Restivus {
    constructor (options?: any);
    public addCollection<T>(collection: Mongo.Collection<T>);
    public addRoute<T>(path: string, conf: {}, routes: {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still get the following error: 'Property addRoute does not exist on type Restivus'. I added all functions inside the class and interfaced with new keyword but nothing works. Any other idea I could try? Oh and if I put the Restivus class into a module I get the error that Module.Restivus(options) is no function.

Comment: I took a look at meteor-restivus and I see now that the API changed, and that definition is just outdated. I don't know the specifics of that project, but I'll add a new definition that works with their examples.

Comment: I forgot to add public. Thanks!